# Python: Como transformar um metodo ou uma classe em obsoleto?

Tags: python

Desta vez quero aprender sobre estruturas em pacotes Python, e preciso da ajuda dos senhores novamente.

Como transformar um método ou uma classe em obsoleto? Como exibir uma mensagem no debugger do interpretador, quando um método ou classe não são mais suportadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa seria o uso de uma biblioteca pronta que incorpore um decorador ao seus projetos, como por exemplo a biblioteca [Deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/deprecated/)

para instalar você pode usar o pip:

```
pip install deprecated
```

e aplicar ao seu código dessa maneira:

```py
from deprecated import deprecated

@deprecated(version='1.2.0', reason="Voce deveria usar outra função")
def some_old_function(x, y):
   return x + y
```

Answer (score 3):

Para emitir a mensagem de função obsoleta, utilize o método *warn* ou *showwarning* do módulo [*warnings*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/warnings.html):

Exemplo:

```
import warnings

def funcao_obsoleta():
    # Habilita avisos de "obsoleto", que, a princípio, são ignorados
    warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
    # Emite o aviso
    warnings.showwarning("Esta função é obsoleta",
        category=DeprecationWarning,
        filename=__file__,
        lineno=25
        )
    # Restaura o status dos avisos
    warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)
    # Corpo da função
    print("Função")
    return

funcao_obsoleta()
```

Saída:

```
x.py:25: DeprecationWarning: Esta função é obsoleta
  category=DeprecationWarning,
Função
```

---

Caso prefira criar um [*decorator*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
import functools
import warnings

# Cria o decorator
def obsoleto(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def deco(*args, **kwargs):
        # Emite o aviso
        warnings.simplefilter('always', DeprecationWarning)
        warnings.warn("Esta função é obsoleta", category=DeprecationWarning)
        warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)
        # Executa a função
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return deco

# Função com o decorator

@obsoleto
def funcao_obsoleta2():
    print("Função 2")
    return

funcao_obsoleta2()
```

Saída:

```
x.py:11: DeprecationWarning: Esta função é obsoleta
  warnings.warn("Esta função é obsoleta", category=DeprecationWarning)
Função 2
```